# How to push notification on Event trigerred with Cloud Functions

Tags: javascript, android, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble creating a function that pushes a notification when a certain event happens in my RealTimeDatabase.
Currently I have been able to extract this function from the web, since I dont know  almost anything abouth JavaScript, I dont know exactly what is this doing..

```
    const functions = require('firebase-functions');

var admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp();


exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('/tareas/{userId}/{tareasId}').onWrite((change, context) => {

  // Grab the current value of what was written to the Realtime Database.
  var descripcion = change.after.ref.parent.child('descripcion'); 
   var lista = change.after.ref.parent.child('lista');
   const snapshot = change.after.val;

  // Get the current userId
  var userId = change.params.userId

  // Notification details.
  const payload = {
    notification: {
      title: 'Nuevo Plan',
      body: `${descripcion} tienes un plan que completar "${lista}".`,
      sound: 'default',
      //clickAction: 'fcm.ACTION.HELLO',
      // badge: '1'
    },
    data: {
      extra: 'extra_data',
    },
  };



// Set the message as high priority and have it expire after 24 hours.
  const options = {
    collapseKey: 'demo',
    contentAvailable: true,
    priority: 'high',
    timeToLive: 60 * 60 * 24,
  };
```

Can someone point me in the right direction, what to add? I have been trying to implement this for hours!

I want the function to push a notification when the date of my Tareas Object is the same as today, and perform this only if the user has activated the notification setting.(Which is a boolean stored in the Profile.)

Here is a Screen Shot of my database:
[image]

Any kind of help would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

first, you need a push-token for users or a topic to send to.
In your case, I think topic is the right choice, because your users could subscribe to it by a simple call like:

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().subscribeToTopic("news")
```

Then you can write your cloud function by returning a message from adminAPI like:

```
return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("news", payload, options);
```

Your realtime database-trigger looks almost correct. Just give it a try :)

Comment: Do i need to implement the FirebaseMessaging? I just want to push Notifications when certain event happens on the database

Comment: Yes, you have to implement Cloud Messaging on client side for this solution.